# Is Internet Explorer 9 (IE9) leaking during ajax / web service calls?

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, memory-leaks

I think I may have discovered quite a bad memory leak in Internet Explorer 9. It seems that when doing AJAX calls to a web service, IE9 leaks memory each time. In fact it seems to leak more memory than the size of the transfer involved.

If you watch the IE9 process in task manager you see the memory usage climb (and never fall). The browser eventually uses ~1.5GB of memory at which point the application crashes. Obviously this would be a problem if you are trying to develop an AJAX web app that is meant to stay running for days at a time.

This behaviour does not occur on IE8, Chrome or Firefox. I have also tested IE9 with all addons disabled.

Below is some ASP.NET 2.0 code that can reproduce the problem (you will need the MS ASP.NET AJAX extensions if you wish to try it):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebServiceLeakTest._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Web Service Leak Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery-1.7.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="json2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">        
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            resultsArea = jQuery("#results");                       
            resultsArea.html(iterationCount);                
            GetData();                        
        });

        var resultsArea;

        var iterationCount = 0;                

        var useJQuery = false;

        var waitInterval = 1500;

        function GetData()
        {
            if(useJQuery)
            {
                $.ajax(
                    {
                        url: "TestWebService.asmx/GetSomeData",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: ReceiveData,
                        error: ReceiveError
                    });
            }
            else
            {            
                WebServiceLeakTest.TestWebService.GetSomeData(ReceiveData, ReceiveError);
            }
        }

        function ReceiveData(data)
        {
            resultsArea.html(iterationCount++);                
            setTimeout(GetData, waitInterval);
        }

        function ReceiveError(error)
        {

        }
    </script>    
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            <Services>       
                <asp:ServiceReference Path="TestWebService.asmx" />
            </Services>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div id="results">
        !
    </div>    
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

You will notice from the code that the results returned from the web service call are not even stored in the javascript client; it merely updates a counter when the web service returns.

Also, this problem occurs when using either the auto-generated client stubs from the ServiceReference or when using jQuery (change 'useJQuery' to true). I have also tried using jQuery with json2.js for the (de)serialisation with jQuery, but this made no apparent difference.

Here is the code for the test web service:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Script.Services;

namespace WebServiceLeakTest
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [ToolboxItem(false)]
    [ScriptService]
    public class TestWebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        const int NUMBER_OF_RECORDS = 10;

        [WebMethod]
        public List<TestData> GetSomeData()
        {
            List<TestData> data = new List<TestData>(NUMBER_OF_RECORDS);

            for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_RECORDS; i++)
            {
                TestData record = new TestData(
                    Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                    Properties.Resources.LorumIpsum);

                data.Add(record);
            }

            return data;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can probably see, it doesn't do much special. It returns some dumb objects containing 3 string properties. Each of these dumb objects is populated with 2 GUIDs and about 70KB of arbitrary text. Therefore, each call to the web service is returning ~700KB.

If you try this out, you will need to increase the max JSON transfer length in your web.config file.

e.g. <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="10000000" />

I have searched the web, MSDN etc but can not find anything useful or informative regarding this problem.

Has anyone else encountered this? Am I doing something wrong? Can anyone else reproduce this problem? Have I found a bad memory leak in IE9?

Regards,
James

Answer (score 1):

The issue has to do with json parsing of the response I believe. I ran into a similar problem and isolated it to that.

Change you dataType to 'text' and you will see no more leaks. I think this has to do with jQuery using eval() for json parsing.

Anyway, I found a library [json_parse.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) which parses the json recursively. This worked for me on IE9. I didn't test it on any other browser only because the website I'm working on is only for IE.

Answer (score 0):

This is AJAX leak problem caused by Jquery, I dont know which part of Jquery causing the leak though. It happened in IE7 and IE9 for me, I didnt bother to try with IE8 though

Proves:

```
$.ajax({
     url : '/sometestservice',
     dataType : "json",
     success : function () {}
});
```

repeat this every second will eat up your RAM soon enough, now try this

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){};
xmlhttp.open("GET","/sometestservice",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

So, I would say write your own ajax code.

---

Update:
It turn out the ajax code in jQuery didnt leak but itsJSON parsing does.

To reproduce repeat this to see the leak

```
var text = "{";
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    text += "\"abc" + i + "\":10000000000000,";
}
text = text.substring(0, text.length -1);
text += "}";
( new Function( "return " + text) )();
```

Well I don't know if this would help but I fix the leak in my webapp by overriding JSON parsing in jQuery, using json_parse.js from https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js.
This is a library from Douglas Crockford, note that json2 (which is pretty popular) is leaky cos it use eval()

That's all from me.

Comment: It happens when using the asp.net generated client side proxies as well so I don't think it's anything to do with jQuery in this case.  For example when executing:  WebServiceLeakTest.TestWebService.GetSomeData(ReceiveData, ReceiveError);  Also, this problem isn't happening on IE7 or IE8 for me, only IE9.

Comment: Hey @JamesEngica did you ever find a solution for this?  I am having the same problem viewing a page in Win 7 IE 9.  I have a recurring ajax call that fills a table with updated data every 2 seconds.  I found what I believe is a memory leak that is not an issue in Win 7 Firefox or Win XP IE 8.  In my testing I rewrote the jquery ajax call to instead use an XMLHttpRequest and found that the leak was still occurring.

Comment: **Update:** I think this has something to do with IE 9 compatibility mode.  When in compatibility mode the cpu usage is really jumpy IE 9 jumps from 79,504 K to 91,666 K in the span of 1 minute.  When not in compatibility mode the number fluctuates between 80,212 K and 80,988 K.  Has anyone else run into memory issues like this with IE 9 in compatibility mode?

Comment: Hi - No I didn't find a solution although I might be getting some MS support on this issue soon. I'll let you know if I get an answer.